# Esper: events not pass to subscriber when using group-by clause

Tags: group-by, esper

I use Nesper (4.1.2/4.5.0) and I have a problem: events not pass to subscriber when using group-by clause.

EPL query:

`select Operation, count(*) as OperationCount from OperationEvent.win:time(10 sec) group by Operation`

output last every 5 sec

Subscriber

```
public void Update(IDictionary<string, object>[] insertStream, IDictionary<string, object>[] removeStream) 
{ ... }
```

When I remove group by clause then everything works nice.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. When I add map instead of type in `AddEventType` method everything works correct. I send event as a map (IDictionary<>), not an object.

Right solution:

`var map = eventType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToDictionary(property => property.Name, property => (object) property.PropertyType);`

`_epService.EPAdministrator.Configuration.AddEventType(eventType.Name, map);`